# How to make an admin user using sign up with google gem in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth, google-signin

I am making an app that I want to only use google to log in (because I am using other google api and i want to sync account.) I also want admin to be able to make other user admin too.

I want to make some user admin, but if they are log in with google, how can i make this exception in controller? 
Is it best to save specific user in database? 
I'm so confuse! please help.

right now this is what i have for admin

**omniauth for checking google login**

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < ApplicationController
    def google_oauth2
        if auth_details.info['email'].split("@")[1] == "company_name.net"
            user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
            if user.persisted?
                flash.notice = "Signed in Through Google!"
                sign_in_and_redirect user
            else
                session["devise.user_attributes"] = user.attributes
                flash.notice = "Please provide a password"
                redirect_to new_user_registration_url
            end
        else
            render :text => "Sorry this site is for company_name employees only"
        end
    end
end
```

**migration for admin to user**

```
class AddAdminToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :admin, :boolean, :default => true
  end
end
```

**table for user roles**

```
class CreateRoles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :roles do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**HaveAndBelongToMany migration**

```
class UsersHaveAndBelongToManyRoles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :roles_users, :id => false do |t|
        t.references :role, :user
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :roles_users
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you probably want to make new users default to NOT being admins, and only set that admin boolean to true if a current admin later makes them an admin.

To authenticate people, I suggest using the [omniauth](https://rubygems.org/gems/omniauth) gem with one of the Google strategies. It will help validate their credentials against the user's Google account. Then you can store any information about that user relevant to your app, including whether they're an admin, in your own database, and use that information for authorization within your app. Hope that helps.

Comment: hi, thank you for response! So just to understand. I should make :default => false. 
I should edit question, I am using omniauth and i have omniauth controller. what is something i should store in order to make this work? And how should i store it? do i make action in omniauth controller or user controller? Thank you for your help!